# Solr 4.4 API / documentation

Tags: solr, indexing

I'm trying to figure out what `org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder` is doing.
More specifically:

- In which states of the indexing life-cycle
- and in which situations it calls which callback-methods

  of the configured **EntityProcessor**.

(The DocBuilder class is not so easy one on the eyes)

Basically what I'm asking for is either:
***a)*** URL for GOOD documentation about DocBuilder / EntityProcessor (Some sort of Flowchart or Sequence diagram would be terrific) or

***b)*** Some kind soul explaining to me what's stated above